# Obtain Bearer Token using HttpClient

Tags: c#, oauth, dotnet-httpclient

I am trying to obtain bearer token:

```
public override async Task<string> Post(string path, HttpContent content) {


    var encodedConsumerKey = System.Uri.EscapeDataString("1111111111111");
    var encodedConsumerKeySecret = System.Uri.EscapeDataString("2222222222222");
    var encodedPair = Base64Encode(String.Format("{0}:{1}", encodedConsumerKey, encodedConsumerKeySecret));

    HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage{
                                        Method      = HttpMethod.Post,
                                        RequestUri  = new Uri("https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token"),
                                        Content     = new StringContent("grant_type=client_credentials")
                                    };
    request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", String.Format("BASIC {0}", encodedPair));
    request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");


    var result = await HttpClient.SendAsync(request);
    return result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
}

private static string Base64Encode(string plainText) {
    var plainTextBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);
    return System.Convert.ToBase64String(plainTextBytes);
}
```

This is giving me the following error 403 'Forbidden'. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: You're invoking `OAuth2` authentication with "basic" bearer authentication? Not sure that's going to fly.

Comment: Sure it'll fly. That's how Twitter's [app-only authentication](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/application-only) works.

Comment: Correct, I am using app-only authentication. However, it keeps giving me that darn 403 error.

Comment: ***Bearer Token*** is ***ONLY*** for `OAuth2` ?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I was able to get this working. I changed a couple of things in the code above. First is setting the `ContentType`

```
requestToken.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded") {CharSet = "UTF-8"};
```

Second is one very small detail I missed, lowering the case of the `Basic` string in the `Authorization` header.

Here's the complete method just in case anyone would need it:

```
public async Task<string> GetAPI(string apiPath)
{

var baseUri = new Uri("https://api.twitter.com/");
var encodedConsumerKey = HttpUtility.UrlEncode("111111111111");
var encodedConsumerKeySecret = HttpUtility.UrlEncode("222222222222");
var encodedPair = Base64Encode(String.Format("{0}:{1}", encodedConsumerKey, encodedConsumerKeySecret));

var requestToken = new HttpRequestMessage
{
    Method = HttpMethod.Post,
    RequestUri = new Uri(baseUri, "oauth2/token"),
    Content = new StringContent("grant_type=client_credentials")
};

requestToken.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded") { CharSet = "UTF-8" };
requestToken.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", String.Format("Basic {0}", encodedPair));

var bearerResult = await HttpClient.SendAsync(requestToken);
var bearerData = await bearerResult.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var bearerToken = JObject.Parse(bearerData)["access_token"].ToString();

var requestData = new HttpRequestMessage
{
    Method = HttpMethod.Get,
    RequestUri = new Uri(baseUri, apiPath),
};
requestData.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", String.Format("Bearer {0}", bearerToken));

var results = await HttpClient.SendAsync(requestData);
return await results.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

}
```

Comment: I take it that the comment about lowering the case of `Basic` is not actually done in the sample code?

Comment: this can also be done with additional parameters in StringContent:
new StringContent(postQuery, Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")

Comment: ***OAuth1*** or ***OAuth2*** version ?

Comment: `ConsumerKey` and `ConsumerSecret` is like  *client_id and client_secret* in _OAuth2_ ?

Comment: I'm just thinking like do we have ngGet package to get access token?

Comment: It works, but it looks ugly.

Answer (score 1):

### Simplified solution

I had a similar requiremenet and ended up with a more elegant solution that I would like to share. This is a simplified version that just fetches the response from the OAuth2 server and returns it, but it can easily be adapted to be used with `HttpClientFactory`, dependency injection or in any other way you need.

```
private async Task<Authorization?> Authorize()
{
    var httpClient = new HttpClient();

    var clientId = HttpUtility.UrlEncode("");     // Put your client ID here
    var clientSecret = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(""); // Put your client secret here
    var authorizationToken = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"{clientId}:{clientSecret}"));

    httpClient.BaseAddress = new(""); // Put your OAuth2 server base address here (with trailing slash)
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new("Basic", authorizationToken);
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new("application/json")); // This might need to be adjusted, depending on your response format

    FormUrlEncodedContent authorizationRequestContent = new(new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        { "grant_type", "client_credentials" }  // Add dictionary entries according to your needs
    });

    var responseMessage = await httpClient.PostAsync("", authorizationRequestContent); // Put here the relative URL to the endpoint (without slash at the beginning)
    var authorization = await responseMessage.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<Authorization>(); // Define your response as a class for deserialization

    return authorization;
}
```

Comment: I would point to couple things that are in line with best practices:
1) httpclient should be used with care, usually one instance per application is sufficient
2) instead of updating httpclient's instance, make these config related settings part of the request.

Comment: Your comments regarding the URLs were most helpful- thank you!